# paramiko module is not catching the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get Kafka lags using paramiko module to catch sum of the kafka lag but the output always giving zero using python paramiko ssh module, while manually same command giving the correct result.

```
    # check list of consumers
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("/home/prduser/kafka_2.12-2.1.0/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:19092,localhost:29092,localhost:39092 --list")
        list_consumers = stdout.readlines()
        print(list_consumers)
# check lag for each consumer
        for consumer in list_consumers:
            print(consumer)
            # | awk '{sum += $5} END {print sum}'
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("/home/prduser/kafka_2.12-2.1.0/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:19092,localhost:29092,localhost:39092 --describe --group {{0}} | awk '{{sum+=$5}} END {{print sum}}' ".format(consumer))
            consumer_lag_out = stdout.readlines()
            print(consumer_lag_out)
```

sample  output
[image]

manual shell command :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have double curly-brackets in the second ssh command. Change from `--group {{0}} | awk` to `--group {0} | awk`
<del>The full line should be</del> (EDIT: see followup):

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("/home/prduser/kafka_2.12-2.1.0/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:19092,localhost:29092,localhost:39092 --describe --group {0} | awk '{{sum+=$5}} END {{print sum}}' ".format(consumer))
```

This way, `{0}` is replaced by `format` with `consumer` (which you redacted in the image, but looks like it should start with `adapter.`). Otherwise, `consumer` is ignored, and the actual command sent is:

```
/home/prduser/kafka_2.12-2.1.0/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:19092,localhost:29092,localhost:39092 --describe --group {0} | awk '{sum+=$5} END {print sum}'
```

When `format` encounters double-curly-brackets, it simply strips the outer ones. It will not error in this case. For example:

```
>>> consumer = "adapter"
>>> print("value = {{0}}, some brackets = {{inside}}".format(consumer))
value = {0}, some brackets = {inside}
>>> print("value = {0}, some brackets = {{inside}}".format(consumer))
value = adapter, some brackets = {inside}
```

---

Following up with further comments, newlines should be stripped from original output. While the sample image is redacted so much so it hard to read, a simple POC can illustrate the situation:

```
>>> lines = ssh.exec_command("ls / | grep etc")[1].readlines()
>>> lines
['etc\n']
>>> consumer = lines[0]
>>> _, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("ls /{0} | grep init.d".format(consumer))
>>> len(stdout.readlines())
106
>>> # It is unlikely we have 106 files with 'init.d' under /etc/ .. Let's check for errors:
>>> print(stderr.readlines())
["bash: -c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `|'\n", "bash: -c: line 2: ` | grep init.d'\n"]
>>> # Now let's try without newlines:
>>> _, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("ls /{0} | grep init.d".format(consumer.strip()))
>>> print(stdout.readlines())
['init.d\n']
>>> # That's more like it.
```

Therefore, the full line should be:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("/home/prduser/kafka_2.12-2.1.0/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:19092,localhost:29092,localhost:39092 --describe --group {0} | awk '{{sum+=$5}} END {{print sum}}' ".format(consumer.strip()))
```

Comment: Tried the above one with single brace --group {{0}} | awk to --group {0} | awk

Comment: it's not working, it is ignoring the all the content after pipe | and printing everything without selecting column 5 
i mean its only taking till this part 

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("/home/prduser/kafka_2.12-2.1.0/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:19092,localhost:29092,localhost:39092 --describe --group {0}

Comment: its working now with ```consumer.strip()```

Comment: @ValakatlaAshok I updated the answer to handle newlines (they should come from the first `exec_command`, but it was hard to understand from the image attached to the question). Let me know if this works for you